# How to process a wav file with an AnalyzerNode in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to calculate the Fast Fourier transform of a wav file in Typescript.

I was thinking about using a dedicated npm package for this, [like fft.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fft.js), but then I noticed that the standard [AnalyzerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) has a built-in FFT feature. However, I've only seen AnalyzerNode used to process real-time audio streams.

How would you send it data loaded from a generic wav file, either loaded from the filesystem or from any other source (e.g. wav-decoder), and not the microphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `AnalyserNode` only gives you the magnitude of the FFT; the phase part is not included.  However, if that works for you, then you can use an `OfflineAudioContext` and `suspend(time)` to get the FFT (magnitude).  Something like:

```
// Let f be the file that has the wav file.
// c is used only so we can run decodeAudioData.  There are other ways to 
// do this.
let c = new AudioContext();
let b = await fetch(f)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => c.decodeAudioData(buffer));

let oac = new OfflineAudioContext({
  numberOfChannels: b.numberOfChannels,
  length: b.length,
  sampleRate: b.sampleRate});

let a = new AnalyserNode(oac, {fftSize: 1024});

// Suspend the context every fftSize frames so we can get the FFT of 
// the previous fftSize frames.
for (let k = a.fftSize; k < b.length; k += a.fftSize) {
  oac.suspend(k / b.sampleRate)
    .then(() => {
      a.getFloatFrequencyData(fftData);
      // Copy fftData out or do something with it
      });
    .then(() => oac.resume());
}

// We can ignore the buffer that startRendering would return from the
// resolved promise.
await oac.startRendering();
```